# Position of a figure

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force figure placement in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text)
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)
>   [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)

I'm having a few definitions and some graphics. I want to have the following structure

```
Definition1

Figure1

Definition2

Figure2

Definition3

Figure3
```

The problem is that the document looks like this:

```
Definition1

Figure1

Definition2

Definition3
```

An on the next page, I suddenly have both figures at the top

```
Figure2

Figure3
```

How can I achieve the positioning I want, without LaTeX repositioning the figures?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please use the search options before posting a new question or check the list of possible duplicates which is displayed while creating a new question. This is the most frequent LaTeX question of all time (here and everywhere) and we have it now in dozens of different form, most of them closed as duplicates. Note that `figure` are supposed to float to the next top or bottom of the following pages, as it is good style and always done in professional books. You can use `\label` and `\ref` to link to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `\usepackage{float}` at the beginning of your texfile and `\begin{figure}[H]` just before you figure. The `H` there forces LaTeX to display the image at the position where it was defined (usually people go with `ht` or `htb`)

Comment: I am already using 'float' with 'h'. It makes no difference. Edit: AHHH, there is a difference between `h` and `H`

Comment: If the figure is placed wrong, you can also use `\usepackage{here}` in combination with `H`. It will "force" the figure to stay where it should be.